# How to reset UIImageView transform property

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my project i am doing following activity on UIImageView 
1.) rotate it
2.) move it
3.) zoom it.
My project also has a button named as "New" which will reset all settings of app.my problem is that if i have rotate the image and click on new button,setting of UIImageVIew is not change. can some one has any idea.Thanks in advance

```
-(void)rotate:(id)sender {

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform oldTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(oldTransform,rotation);

    [[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}
```

above code i am using for rotation.

Comment: Reset in the sense ? The image will be rotated back to orinigal position right ?

Comment: Please post some of ur code.....We might help u then

Comment: @iphoneFreak thanks for response. Yes.it is.

Comment: Probably you have to save temporally the position (frame) of your images and add some flag to know if the image has already moved, then reset the image with the frame that you have saved.

Answer (score 14):

If `imageView` is your `UIImageView` object, resetting the `transform` property is done using,

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Additionally, you can shorten the `rotate:` method a bit if you are not using `lastRotation` anywhere else.

```
-(void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    UIView * view = gesture.view;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, gesture.rotation);
    gesture.rotation = 0;
}
```

Comment: in swift 3, it's been changed to imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity;

Answer (score -1):

For another practical `Swift` example for those who are interested, I was able to build off of Deepak's example for rotating an image, then reversing the rotation by using an extension for `UIImageView`

```
extension UIImageView {

    func rotateCounterClockwise() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI))
        })
    }

    func rotateToOriginal() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })
    }
}
```